# What's wrong with my WHILE-DO loop, or why my script can't find the file I'm giving it on a plate?

Tags: bash, while-loop, do-while

I have a problem with BASH script - a bit more complex problem that it seems to be.

First and important thing: **there is no way for me to use** `globstar` **in this script**

Let me begin with my folder structure:

```
config--
       |-config-chain.conf
       |
       |--folder1--
                  |-somefile1.txt
                  |-somefile2.txt
                  |-somefile3.txt
       |--folder2--
                  |-somefile4.txt
                  |-somefile5.txt
                  |-somefile6.txt
```

I need to build strings based on what is in `config-chain.conf` and what is in all the other files, like `somefile1.txt`.

Let me assume that `config-chain.conf` looks like this:

```
somefile1
somefile2
somefile3
somefile4
somefile5
somefile6
```

And `somefile1` looks like this:

```
someconfiguration1
someconfiguration2
someconfiguration3
someconfiguration4
someconfiguration5
```

This loop is basically ment to build strings like:

```
somefile1.someconfiguration1
somefile1.someconfiguration2
somefile1.someconfiguration3
somefile1.someconfiguration4
somefile1.someconfiguration5
```

etc.

What the script does is not so important here, but - the problem is that it doesnt seem to be able to find the file I'm giving it. Here is the loop. It is runned from the `config` directory.

```
while read -r DATA1 ; do

    FILEPATH=$(find . -name "$DATA1-test.txt")

        while read -r CONFIG ; do

            #Doing something here

        done < "$FILEPATH"

done < $DATAFILE
```

The output from Jenkins looks like this:

```
00:00:44.705 + read -r DATA1
00:00:44.705 ++ find . -name somefile1-test.txt
00:00:44.707 + FILEPATH=./folder1/somefile1-test.txt

00:00:44.709 bvt/engine/berichte_vergleichs_test.sh: line 218: somefile1-test.txt: File or directory not found
```

I am loosing my mind here... I've tried many possibilities, but NOTHING is working for me...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was mislead by the output from Jenkins, especially the line saying:

```
00:00:44.709 bvt/engine/berichte_vergleichs_test.sh: line 218: somefile1-test.txt: File or directory not found
```

There was everything fine with this line, there was a mistake in another loop. I haven't mentioned that I have another `do-while` loop embedded in the main `do-while` loop, to be honest, I have just forgotten about it.

The real loop looks like this:

```
while read -r DATA1 ; do

    FILEPATH=$(find . -name "$DATA1-test.txt")

        while read -r CONFIG ; do

            #Doing something here

        done < "$FILEPATH"

        while read -r CONFIG ; do

            #Doing something here

        done < "$FILEPATH"

done < $DATAFILE
```

The reason why I need more while loops here is not so important. The real mistake was here:

```
while read -r DATA1 ; do

    FILEPATH=$(find . -name "$DATA1-test.txt")

        while read -r CONFIG ; do

            #Doing something here

        done < $DATA1-test.txt
```

> **I have forgotten about this loop and I have forgotten to change it to**
>   **`"$FILEPATH"`... I just changed it in the second loop, and that wasnt**
>   **enough.**

```
        while read -r CONFIG ; do

            #Doing something here

        done < "$FILEPATH"

done < $DATAFILE
```